# GORM Basic undestandig problems

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I am trying to understand how GORM works.
Building a Database for projects with buildings and buildingparts(areas of a great building) doesn`t work the way I want it to. What I want is: each project has one building and one of the buildingpart of that building.

I tried it that way:

```
class Project {
    String name
    static hasOne = [building: Building]
    Buildingpart buildingpart
    String toString(){
        return name
    }
}

class Building {
    String name
    static hasMany = [projects: Project, buildingparts: Buildingpart]
    String toString(){
        return name
    }
}

class Buildingpart {
    String buildingpart
    static belongsTo = [building: Building]
    String toString(){
        return buildingpart
    }
}
```

Doing it that way gives me a dropdownmenu for every buildingpart and not only the ones from the selectet building.
I would be happy for any suggestions.

Comment: Nothing in your domain model says the buildingpart has to be a buildingpart of the building. You can add custom validation to check this. As far as the dropdown, thats up to you to ensure it is correct.

Comment: @James Kleeh : I though static belongsTo = [building: Building] does that.

Comment: No, it doesn't. The belongsTo in Buildingpart and hasOne in Project are different properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Design looks ok
You probably need an additional hook in the `Building` class something like

```
Buildingpart getCurrentPart(Buildingpart buildingPart) {
return  this.buildingparts.find{buildingPart}
}
```

Then

```
Project project = project.get(id)



 println "project building = ${project.building}"
   println "project buildingparts = ${project.building.buildingparts}"
   println "project currentpart = ${project.building.getCurrentPart(project.buildingpart)}"
```

When you say your select box, this makes no sense to me since to us here we have no idea what that all means Also a note in your project class it is called :

`Bauteil buildingpart`

then you have hasMany  `buildingparts: Buildingpart]`

The thing you need to pay attention to is the binding happening in println and shown below:

when you then query the buiding many parts for the object from project

`project.building.getCurrentPart(project.buildingpart)`

Comment: I corrected that Bauteil buildingpart  to Buildingpart buildingpart, i forgot to translate that.